# get the current index of pathHistory in react-router v4

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

This is how my `props.history.pathHistory` looks like:

[image]

Let's say the user plays with `history.goBack()` and `history.goForward()`

Is there any built-in method inside `react-router` to know the current index if the `pathHistory` array?
If not, please provide a solution.

**The goal** here is to prevent the user to go back to the login page using back.

Comment: why don't you just make two routes rules , one for guest user and another for login user. In that way you do not take need to worry  about  back or forward issues.

Comment: After successful login use history.replace(location) instead of  history.push(location) and you /login page will be replaced with redirect url

Comment: @IgorStetsiura that's a good solution for my case. Thanks.

Comment: @Cristian Muscalu Can I add this answer and you mark it ✓? :)

Answer (score -2):

You can access `history.index` so you can do this:

```js
history.index > 1 && <BackButton />
```

In case of MemoryRouter, `canGo` is implemented:

```js
history.canGo(-1) && <BackButton />
```

Note that Typescript will not recognize either of these.